# Standardize range of data based on one of the dataframe's column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a pandas.dataframe with a column `passengers` with a range which may vary greatly depending on the function creating the dataframe.

The other columns are often more or less of constant ranges (they're economy indicators).

```
segments.head(2);

            passengers       gdp  gdp_per_capita  inflation  unemployment  \
Month                                                                       
2002-01-01       11688  4461.087       31634.953    150.847        14.418   
2002-02-01        9049  4142.153       29321.702    204.132        14.738   

            population  
Month                   
2002-01-01      339.59  
2002-02-01      343.32
```

My most valuable data is the number of passengers, so I do not want to transform it. However, the differences of scale of the other measures, which I want to use as predictors, make it difficult to track the variations (sometimes in tens of thousands, sometimes in decimals).

How could I standardize the range of all my columns to be consistent with the `mean(passengers)`?

Comment: Suppose you want to scale `population` -- you will need to manually change that scale yourself, depending on the ultimate number of significant digits you want. So if that `339.59` is really `339,590,000` people, you would have to manually multiply that column by `1,000,000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways you can approach that problem, you can make/apply a manual transformation function, or you can use a pre existing function, such as ***sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler***.

StandardScaler will "*Standardize features by removing the mean and scaling to unit variance*". You can hence shift mean and adjust unit variance accordingly to your desires/needs.

However, it looks to me you are going to try and build a predictive model on that data, if so,the best approach would be to test all hypothesis, and keep what works best, my advice is:

- Remove skew from passagers (if present) - Log & Log1p are most common transforms, but depending on your data other  transforms might be better. You should test arbitrary functions as well (inverse, or 1/(X+1) for example) and use the best transform (skew closest to 0)
- Test both scaled / non scaled features. If data is skewed test both with transform/without as above.
- If outliers are present test both with and without (outliers converted to borderline values / outliers converted to np.nan) Make a boolean feature column identifying outliers for each feature. Test to see if its valuable information or just noise to the model.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks, it does. 
I indeed am trying to build a predictive model with these variables.

Comment: an easy way to evaluate the changes is to use a fixed seed and the sklearn function cross_val_score. best of luck ;)